# Accessing the username of a user being edited from the model in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, model

From the model, how do I access the username of a user being edited in CakePHP 2.4?

I'm using Miles Johnson's excellent file uploader for userpics in my Cake 2.4 app, using a callback in the behavior's actsAs config to determine the name the file will get saved under:

`'nameCallback' => 'getUserName',`

which calls the following function:

```
    public function getUserName() {
    return CakeSession::read("Auth.User.username");
}
```

This works great when it's a user editing their own picture, but it all comes apart when it's an *admin* editing that user: The callback returns the admin's username, not the user's.

The file uploader uploads the file and saves it under a filename and location specified by the ActsAs config: In this case, I'm having it save the images under `/webroot/img/uploads`, using the `getUserName()` function to get a username for the filename. The uploader then saves the file's URL in the User model under the field `image`.

Comment: update your question with photo table and user table details...

Comment: I understand what you are trying... But its hard to make a solution without more details... I asked for table details like users table has column id, username etc.....Now, good idea is to update your question with `Controller action` and with the `view` file and also about `tables` you have for saving photo `url`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AuthComponent::user('usernane')` to get the value if a user.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

If your user is assigned a role_id or a group_id or even a different type that separates it from an admin account you could try...

```
if(AuthComponent::user('role_id') != 1){ //1 being the role assigned to the admin
 return AuthComponent::user('username');
}
```

see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html for an example on role based authentication

Comment: That does the same thing as what I was already using: `AuthComponent::user('username');` returns the username of the currently logged-in user. I'm trying to figure out how to get the callback to return the username of the user being edited, who may not be the user doing the editing.